# Сохранение SVG параметров в CSS фаил

Tags: svg, css-animation, graphics

Добрый день уважаемые, столкнулся с таким вопросом что после того как достал svg фаил сконвертированный в Illustrtor получил огромное количество повторяющихся элементов. Приведу пример

```
<radialGradient id="SVGID_1_" cx="58.792" cy="113.0993" r="3.5393" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#E6FFFA"/>
    <stop  offset="0.4946" style="stop-color:#83CCFA"/>
    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#266DC4"/>
</radialGradient>
<circle class="st1" cx="58.8" cy="113.1" r="3.5"/>
<radialGradient id="SVGID_2_" cx="86.651" cy="186.2081" r="3.5384" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#E6FFFA"/>
    <stop  offset="0.4946" style="stop-color:#83CCFA"/>
    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#266DC4"/>
</radialGradient>
<circle class="st2" cx="86.7" cy="186.2" r="3.5"/>
<radialGradient id="SVGID_3_" cx="66.4336" cy="185.2397" r="3.5387" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#E6FFFA"/>
    <stop  offset="0.4946" style="stop-color:#83CCFA"/>
    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#266DC4"/>
</radialGradient>
<circle class="st3" cx="66.4" cy="185.2" r="3.5"/>
```

Здесь вы можете увидеть 3 круга с **ОДИНАКОВЫМИ радиальными градиентами**, в CSS файле к ним обращаюсь через стили

```
.st0{fill:none;stroke:#5FBEFF;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
.st1{fill:url(#SVGID_1_);}
.st2{fill:url(#SVGID_2_);}
.st3{fill:url(#SVGID_3_);}
```

Вопрос, как можно сократить(оптимизировать) данную запись через таблицу стилей CSS? 
ПС Дело в том что у меня этих кругов >200 и это очень много весит.

Comment: Любой online svg optimizer не подходит?

Comment: Не подходит, они затирают анимацию, и правят слои. Ещё мысли ?